# Access FormData object in Wordpress Rest API Route, send via Ajax

Tags: ajax, wordpress, rest

I have an input field, which of "type file", this is where the user can add the image. I have already added the image into the "FormControl object". My problem now is how do I get my file in my wordpress rest function. So i could move it into my file system. Please see below code:

//html

```
 <div class="column-one">
    <input type="file" name="employee-photo" id="employee-photo"/>
      <div class="upload-photo-warning-msg-container">
         <div class="msg">
         </div>
      </div>
</div>
```

//js

```
$('.upload-photo-container #employee-photo').on('change', function(){
    const photo = this.files[0];
    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append("employeePhoto", photo);
    $.ajax({
       type: 'POST',
           url: myAjax.restURL + 'app/v1/uploadEmployeePhoto',
           data: formData,
           success: function(response){
              msg.empty();
              msg.append($('<p id="required"></p>').text('Uploaded Photo'));
              console.log('SUCCESS RESPONSE: ', response);
           },
           error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
           },
           complete: function(data){
           }
     });
 });
```

//route.php

```
function upload_employee_photo($request){
   //access the data here so i could do something like
   //$location = './img/';  
   //move_uploaded_file($_FILES["employee-photo"]["tmp_name"], $location);
}
```

Can anyone give me a little help on this one. I would greatly appreciate it, i have been struggling with this, in the last days.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

Edit your JS function:

```
$('.upload-photo-container #employee-photo').on('change', function(){
    const photo = this.files[0];
    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append("employeePhoto", photo);
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: myAjax.restURL + 'app/v1/uploadEmployeePhoto',
        method: 'POST',
        beforeSend: function (xhr) {
            xhr.setRequestHeader('X-WP-Nonce', localized.nonce);
        },
        data: formData,
        processData: false,
        contentType: false,
        success: function(response){
           msg.empty();
           msg.append($('<p id="required"></p>').text('Uploaded Photo'));
           console.log('SUCCESS RESPONSE: ', response);
        },
        error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
        },
        complete: function(data){
        }
     });
});
```

Then in your route callback:

```
function upload_employee_photo($request){
    
    $file_params = $request->get_file_params();
    if( isset( $file_params['employeePhoto']['tmp_name'] ) ) {
        $file = file_get_contents( $tmp_name );
        file_put_contents( 'test.jpg', $file );
    }
    //access the data here so i could do something like
    //$location = './img/';  
    //move_uploaded_file($_FILES["employee-photo"]["tmp_name"], $location);
}
```

The `$file_params` variable will contain the multipart form data you may need to perform the file upload process. You can use the `tmp_name` along with `file_get_contents()` and `file_put_contents()` as described above.

Also, please take a look at the `xhr.setRequestHeader('X-WP-Nonce', localized.nonce);` in your JS function as you will need to replace the `localized.nonce` with your own generated nonce.